# keep the coherence in an excel file between 2 sheets

Tags: excel

I have a excel file that contains more then one sheet , I have to make sure that the value in the column that I named 'user' and still the same in every sheet.
How can I do that?
For example I have sheet 1 that contain 2 columns : a user name and code , in the other sheet I have to make sure that the user name an code stays the same for example:

```
application 1:                  
user_name :Sara
code:120
```

In the sheet 2 the user name sarra or sarraa .. it would not be accepted because it's 'Sara'.

Answer (score 0):

I have created "sheet1" and "sheet2". In "sheet1", I have put the name "Sara" in cell A2, and in "sheet2", I have put `=Sheet1!A2` in cell A2.

Are you looking for something like this? (Cross-worksheet references?)